# Does Orange Pi 5 have PTP hardware timestamping support?

Tags: ethernet

I'm looking for information about the Ethernet chip on the Orange Pi 5. I need an SBC that has PTP hardware timestamp support (IEEE 1588). According to OrangePi.org, the Orange Pi 5 has the Motorcomm YT8531C, but I have not been able to find documentation that provides the answer about hardware PTP support. Most likely it does not, but I'd like to confirm on an actual device before purchasing one.

If you have an Orange Pi 5, you can test this with this command:

`ls /sys/class/net |xargs -n1 ethtool -T`

If there is someone that can post the output of this command, I would appreciate it very much. Sorry for the odd question, this is the best StackExchange site I could find to ask this question. I would ask on the OrangePi forum, but it doesn't run HTTPS, so I'd rather not create an account there.

Comment: The armbian forum may be another place to ask.

Comment: Thanks, cross-posted to Armbian forum: https://forum.armbian.com/topic/26913-does-orange-pi-5-have-ptp-hardware-timestamping-support/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does.

https://forum.armbian.com/topic/26913-does-orange-pi-5-have-ptp-hardware-timestamping-support/#comment-160778

A kind user on the armbian forum, @royk, ran the ethtool command, and posted the output which shows:

```
Time stamping parameters for eth0:
Capabilities:
        hardware-transmit
        software-transmit
        hardware-receive
        software-receive
        software-system-clock
        hardware-raw-clock
PTP Hardware Clock: 0
Hardware Transmit Timestamp Modes:
        off
        on
Hardware Receive Filter Modes:
        none
        all
        ptpv1-l4-event
        ptpv1-l4-sync
        ptpv1-l4-delay-req
        ptpv2-l4-event
        ptpv2-l4-sync
        ptpv2-l4-delay-req
        ptpv2-event
        ptpv2-sync
        ptpv2-delay-req
```